# Click button A submit button B at the same time

Tags: javascript, button, click, submit

I want to auto calculate shipping when the quantity changed?
How can "Calculate shipping botton" auto submit when updated quantity?
This script worked in the first time when i clicked to quantity button, it do not work in the next time. I appreciate your help!

```
 <button class="quantity__button" name="minus" type="button">Minus</button>
 <button class="quantity__button" name="plus" type="button">Plus</button>

 <input type="button" class="get-rates" value="CALCULATE SHIPPING" />

  <script>
 $('.quantity__button').click(function(){
 $('.get-rates').click(); 
 })    
 </script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried.

Comment: Hi friend!  I tried with:<button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="minus" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">   <script>
$('button.quantity__button').click(function(){
  $('.get-rates').click(); 
})
    
  </script>